# Why can i not import geotools RasterToVectorFactory to my project?

Tags: java, maven, geotools

I am currently trying to convert a raster file (.tif) into a vector file of polygones. I tried using `geotools` (version 17 or 19) but the import `org.geotools.process.raster.RasterToVectorFactory` could not be resolved with any of these versions. I integrated the `gt-process` dependency to my pom.xml.

This is my method: (`RasterToVecorFactory` and `GT_NAMESPACE` cannot be resolved)

```
private void polygonize(GridCoverage2D coverage) {
        ReferencedEnvelope env = new ReferencedEnvelope(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        /*
         * Parameters for the raster to vector process
         */
        final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put(RasterToVectorFactory.RASTER.key, coverage);
        params.put(RasterToVectorFactory.BAND.key, Integer.valueOf(0));
        params.put(RasterToVectorFactory.BOUNDS.key, env);
        params.put(RasterToVectorFactory.OUTSIDE.key, Collections.singleton(0.0d));
        final Process r2v = Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl(ProcessFactory.GT_NAMESPACE, "RasterToVectorProcess"));
}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>gisprog</groupId>
<artifactId>Area</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Area</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>19-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-extension</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geopkg</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-jts-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell that process doesn't exist any longer (and hasn't since version 2.7). Other than a residual reference in the example of how to call a process in the documentation that you seem to have copied.

You probably want to use the [PolygonExtractionProcess](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-raster/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/raster/PolygonExtractionProcess.java) in the [`gt-process-raster`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/process/process-raster.html) module.